# SQLite database errors with inputting data

Tags: android, sqlite

I've nearly finished creating my first database, however I think some of the syntax in my `oncreate` is wrong. I can't figure out where however? I've tried looking at tutorials and tried to tailor my code towards theirs, but nothing seems to be working.

```
package com.example.bash1.sqlitediss;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database name
public static final String DATABASE_STOCKDB = "Stock.db";
// Column names
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "stock_table";
public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
public static final String COL_3 = "Datereceived";
public static final String COL_4 = "Expirydate";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_STOCKDB, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table stock_table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL_2 + "INTEGER,"+ COL_3 + "INTEGER," + COL_4 +"INTEGER" + ")");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String Name, String Datereceived, String Expirydate){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, Datereceived);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, Expirydate);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

    if (result == -1 )
       return false;
    else
       return true;

    }  
}
```

The error is as follows:

> Error inserting Name=sss Datereceived=s Expirydate=s`
>
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table stock_table has no column named Name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO stock_table(Name,Datereceived,Expirydate) VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: It's obvious that your table stock_table has no column named Name, only reading the exception hints you well . . .

Answer (score 0):

You have `"create table stock_table" + TABLE_NAME` -- you're duplicating the table name. Also there is no space between your column names and their type. Try `COL_1 + " INTEGER..."` for each of your columns.

Also, check you're values passed in to `insertData`. You're passing in String, but defining the columns as INTEGER. Are you sure you don't want TEXT for the columns?

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) for further guidance.

This code worked correctly for me:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
  // Database name
  public static final String DATABASE_STOCKDB = "Stock.db";
  // Column names
  public static final String TABLE_NAME = "stock_table";
  public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
  public static final String COL_2 = "Name";
  public static final String COL_3 = "Datereceived";
  public static final String COL_4 = "Expirydate";


  public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_STOCKDB, null, 1);

  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL_2 + " TEXT,"+ COL_3 + " TEXT," + COL_4 +" TEXT" + ")");
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

    onCreate(db);
  }

  public boolean insertData(String Name, String Datereceived, String Expirydate){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, Name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, Datereceived);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, Expirydate);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if (result == -1 )
      return false;
    else
      return true;

  }

}
```

Also it in possible that the database is in an inconsistent state if you ran the app and then changed the database design/schema and you didn't properly increment the version number. Try fully uninstalling the app and reinstalling as well.

Comment: SHould i remove TABLE_NAME from that line?

Comment: Remove "stock_table". What you have now is essentially, `"create table stock_table stock_table..."`

Comment: Just removed it, leaving it as `       `db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL_2 + " INTEGER,"+ COL_3 + " INTEGER," + COL_4 +" INTEGER" + ")");`
`

The same error is coming up...                    `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table stock_table has no column named Name (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO stock_table(Name,Datereceived,Expirydate) VALUES (?,?,?)`

Thanks again for trying to help

Comment: What values are you passing in to `insertData()`? You're defining all the fields as INTEGER but you're passing in String values.

Comment: Ive just been adding Random letters to test

Comment: That's your issue. You're passing in Strings to INTEGER fields, which are expecting integers. Change the INTEGER for COL_2, COL_3, and COL_4, to TEXT.

Comment: Okay, having changed it.. `       `db.execSQL("create table" + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL_2 + " TEXT,"+ COL_3 + " TEXT," + COL_4 +" TEXT" + ")");`

It still shows the same error as no collum named Name

Comment: @AshleyThompson , try my answer.

Comment: You don't have a space after `"create table"`. Change to `"create table " + TABLE_NAME...`

Comment: Argh, still the same error with         `db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL_2 + " TEXT,"+ COL_3 + " TEXT," + COL_4 +" TEXT" + ")");` 
This is too confusing

Comment: I just took your code and made the modifications I suggested into a sample project and it correctly inserted with no error. Are there any errors before that one in the logs?

Comment: @AshleyThompson I've edited in the code that worked for me to my answer.

Comment: @AshleyThompson also try fully uninstalling the app, then re-build and install. You may have the database in an inconsistent state.

Comment: There errors are before those in the logs, `04-19 15:50:35.423 32564-32564/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
04-19 15:50:35.427 32564-32564/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/OpenGLRenderer: MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
04-19 15:50:35.475 32564-32564/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/OpenGLRenderer: Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()

04-19 15:50:43.375 32564-32564/com.example.bash1.sqlitediss E/SQLiteLog: (1) table stock_table has no column named Name`

Comment: @AshleyThompson Let me know the results of the uninstall, then rebuild/install.

Comment: I just used your code and it still comes up with the same errors for me !

Comment: Sure i will do, im not sure how to unistall etc, so will go look up!

Comment: Open the app drawer on the device/emulator, then find your app and long-click it, then drag to uninstall at the top of the screen.

Comment: OKAY!!!!! I added the data and no error has come up!!!!!
Im going to look in the logs to see if it has saved. 
Thank you so so so much, youve saved me HOURS

Comment: Chances are your app's database was in an inconsistent state, because you changed the table design (added/removed a table). If you do this, be sure to uninstall the app before rebuilding -- your database is only created the first time it is accessed (unless you use the upgrade functionality), so changing any columns will not be reflected unless your uninstall the app.

Comment: Also, be sure to select an answer as accepted if your problem has been solved. Good luck with your development.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that  your create table command has no space between column name and type -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table stock_table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL_2 + "INTEGER,"+ COL_3 + "INTEGER," + COL_4 +"INTEGER" + ")");
}
```

That's why you don't have column "Name" but "NameINTEGER". Similar issue is with other columns too. Also, you are inserting text values but you have integer type columns , so change the columns except the primary key to text type columns. Change it to -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL_2 + " TEXT, "+ COL_3 + " TEXT, " + COL_4 +" TEXT" + ")");
}
```

Comment: Hi Shadab, Having changed it to...         `db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COL_1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+ COL_2 + " TEXT,"+ COL_3 + " TEXT," + COL_4 +" TEXT" + ")");`

Which should now be correct, its showing the error message as having no collum named Name

Comment: Copy exactly the same code I wrote and then let me know. .

Comment: And yes I forgot to mention, try these changes only after uninstalling your app or changing the db version number, otherwise there will be no effect.